# Read Counts for Firebase Firestore list within document

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want to ask something about **read counts of firebase**.

Let's say i have a collection of **posts** and for every **post-doc** i have an array of the **users ids**. Basically storing the **ids** of every user which liked the current post.

Now, let's say i load the data of first **10 posts** and every **post-doc** array field consists of 10,000 **userIds** : ['id1', 'id2' .........'id1000']

So my question here is that what should be the **read count** :

- Is it **10 * 10,000** ? If this is the case then it's really bad.
- Is it only **10** ? The firebase counts the array field as **1 read** no matter it's size.

Basically, i am trying to **implement a system of liking the posts**. Every User can like post but the read count of firebase is somewhat unknown to me.

Any suggestions or help on firebase read counts or this topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> let's say i load the data of first 10 posts and every post-doc array field consists of 10,000 userIds : ['id1', 'id2' .........'id1000']

According to this, you will actually read 10 x documents, and therefor, you will be billed for 10 read requests.

If the document had 1 single field, or as your case, had a list, containing many children, it's still billed the same way => 1 document read.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Are you absolutely sure about this ?

Comment: Yes. The billing is per document read, not per field inside the document. Your list of likes is only a field, regardless of the length of the list in this field. What you do want to pay attention to, is the maximum size of the document, which is `1 mb`. In case you will actually have 1K likes stored in the list, among other fields int he document.
Billing wise, don't worry.

Comment: In addition to being billed per document read, you're also charged for bandwidth consumed. That will of course be higher when there are 10K UIDs in the field than when there's only a few UIDs in there. For details on this, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing#network